# Изменение иконки пункта меню в BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

Есть BroadcastReceiver, который отслеживает статус подключения к сети, если подключение к интернету происходит через wi-fi, то в строковую переменную internetStatus пишется некое слово, если через мобильные данные - другое слово, если нет подключения совсем третье слово. Это работает.

Есть для активности также меню с одним пунктом меню, который будет отображать иконку интернет статуса (если через вай-фай, то иконку вай-фай, если через моб. данные другую иконку и т.д.)

Пытаюсь сделать так как ниже описал, но ошибка выпадает. Вроде при запуске активности ресивер не может найти пункт меню или в это время он еще не создан не знаю. Как правильнее реализовать чтобы иконка в пункте меню менялась автоматически если статус изменился?

```
private BroadcastReceiver NetworkChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        internetStatus = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
        if (internetStatus.equals("Подключение через мобильный интернет")) {
            signalItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_mobile);
        } else if (internetStatus.equals("Подключение через WI-FI")) {
            signalItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_wifi);
        } else if (internetStatus.equals("Нет подключения к интернету")) {
            signalItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_mobile_off);
        }
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.player_menu, menu);
    signalItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_signal);

    return true;
}
```

> Process: ru.fandroid.myapp, PID: 29475 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Error receiving broadcast Intent {
>   act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010
>   launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0
>   mFlags=0 } bqHint=1 (has extras) } in
>   ru.fandroid.myapp.activity.PlayerActivity$2@cd6bede at
>   android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1195)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface
>   method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setIcon(int)' on a
>   null object reference at
>   ru.fandroid.myapp.activity.PlayerActivity$2.onReceive(PlayerActivity.java:196)
>   at
>   android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1185)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)

Comment: Разобрался. invalidateOptionsMenu() метод помог.